Where are favorited songs stored in Beat Saber?
I accidentally erased my custom songs folder for Beat Saber. However, I noticed that when I began redownloading custom songs, songs I'd previously favorited were still marked as favorites in-game. I now want to check which songs I've favorited so I can redownload those custom songs.
Where does Beat Saber store the list of favorited songs?

Not an answer, but have you checked the setings file %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Hyperbolic Magnetism\Beat Saber\settings.cfg (or /steamapps/compatdata/620980/pfx/ on linux)?

@npst Thanks. Favorites were stored in that folder, but under the PlayerData.dat file

On Windows, favorited songs are stored in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Hyperbolic Magnetism\Beat Saber\PlayerData.dat in the section for favoritesLevelIds.
A few notes:

The file may be large as it contains other data, such as the high scores for all played songs.
The data is formatted on a single line by default, making it difficult to read.
Song titles are not stored in the file. They are saved as custom_level_<hash>. If you search the hash for a song, you may be able to find an entry for the track online. For example, 727F16F8BEF6DDB62F7A1ABD3677737F5082A302 matches Flat Zone 2.


A formatted version of the level IDs section
